# How to filter traffic for the address of a name like this?

Tags: wireshark

How to filter traffic for the address of type: `p309-pmr.ii.ucla.edu.uk`?

What kinds of servers are generally these types of names given to : `p309-pmr.ii.ucla.edu.uk`?

Is this a DNS server or IP server?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Those are DNS names for hosts, and you can't know by the name if it is an end-user PC, phone, server, or anything else by the DNS name. DNS is an application layer protocol that isn't used by the network; the DNS name must be translated to an IP address before the network can use it.

It really depends on what you are using to filter traffic, but many devices which filter traffic can only do it by IP address, not DNS name.

Comment: I can filter the address of that server like `ip.addr == 192.168.1.2`.   But, why isn't it possible to filter it by using `ip.addr == p309-pmr.ii.ucla.edu.uk`?

Comment: IP doesn't use DNS names, applications do. DNS is an application layer protocol, not a network protocol.

Comment: OK. Then how can I filter by using a DNS name?

Comment: You need a device capable of that. The device would need to do a reverse DNS lookup of each and every packet coming in to see if the source IP address in the packet matches the DNS name, and it would need to query a DNS server for this information. This would be very slow, and it would bring your link to a crawl. Applications do DNS lookups to get the IP address to use before sending a packet out. There is nothing in IP that knows anything about names. DNS was invented to translate between the much more human-friendly name and IP addresses, but IP knows nothing about names.

Comment: "But, why isn't it possible to filter it by using `ip.addr == p309-pmr.ii.ucla.edu.uk`?"  It *should* be possible; that's a Wireshark display filter, and Wireshark *should* be able to look up `p309-pmr.ii.ucla.edu.uk` in DNS, get an IP address, and compare against that IP address.  If that doesn't work, file a bug in [the Wireshark Bugzilla](http://bugs.wireshark.org).

Comment: @GuyHarris, I assumed he meant to filter for addresses of names in a firewall since he wanted to filter traffic. An application, like Wireshark can certainly use DNS, but asking a firewall to do a reverse DNS lookup for every packet coming through is just not practical.

Comment: The long way that you can do is to make  an DIG to the address and known who is behind this domain, like people here said, could be something, and could response to various IP. Then, once time you get those IPs, you can put on the rule on your device or software. You need to understand that IPs behind that domain can change, then, you need to check periodically that domain, and update or not, your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

This is a domain name an could be anything, from a phone, server, workstation,.. an so on. I think first you need to know the IP behind this domain name, i hope you only find an IP address, on this way you are lucky, if not, an you encounter some hostnames behind this domain name, then, you need to study the traffic, and wich kind of traffic do you need to filter.